# Python numpy and pandas for machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

just as a disclaimer, this question is in regards to  schoolwork. Literally though, my professor said to use this site for aid.

I am taking machine learning, and while our professor is a brilliant mathematician, he may be a little lacking on the programming side of things.

The name of the game here is to read code portions and find/fix the mistake.

I spend hours on this part, and I reckon my issue is having a dot product between a dataframe and numpy zeroes.

Issues occur like unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

I tried reading documentation and this site for a workaround, but I very novice in programming, especially a library like numpy and pandas

This is programming with python pandas

```
# Initialize the paarmeter set theta with zeros length as equal to column size in X
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
theta = np.zeros(X.shape[1], dtype = int)
print(theta)


def cost_function(X, y, theta):
    """
    cost_function(X, y, theta) computes the cost of using theta as the
    parameter for linear regression to fit the data points in X and y
    """
    ## number of training examples
    m = len(y) 

    ## Calculate the cost with the given parameters
    J = 1/(2*m)*np.sum((X.dot(theta)-y)**2)

    return J

#Initial cost
cost_function(X,y,theta)
```

running the last line yields the most issues.

Comment: What is the value of `y`?

Comment: @MarcusLim y = np.array(housing1_clean.iloc[:,-1]) ....I am a bit shamed to say I was never formally taught all this syntax.

Comment: I am running this in jupyter notebook

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide the result of the following: `X.dtypes` and `y.dtype`? The error you get is a result of attempting to add a float (number with a fractional part) to a string (a sequence of characters). In some cases, numbers may, accidentally or intentionally, be stored as a string, since digits are characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `np.dot(X,theta)` instead of `X.dot(theta)`. Here is the edited code.

```
def cost_function(X, y, theta):
"""
cost_function(X, y, theta) computes the cost of using theta as the
parameter for linear regression to fit the data points in X and y
"""
## number of training examples
    m = len(y) 

## Calculate the cost with the given parameters
    J = 1/(2*m)*np.sum((np.dot(X,theta)-y)**2)

    return J

#Initial cost
cost_function(X,y,theta)
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! It does help greatly. I finished the class, but I appreciate when anyone kindly spends time out of their day to help others! Especially with an older question!